# Getting result of a Future after submitting function to java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService

Tags: clojure, java.util.concurrent

The following works.  The result is "hello world"

```
  (def ^Callable f (fn [] "hello world"))
  (let [e (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newSingleThreadExecutor)]
    (try
      (.get (.submit e f))
      (finally (.shutdown e))))
```

But the following doesn't.  The result of `get` is `nil`

```
(def e (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newSingleThreadExecutor))
(.get (.submit e f))
```

Why?  I checked that `f` is getting called by replacing it with something that has a side effect.  The only difference I can see is that `e` is bound using `let` in one and `def` in the other.

Another question.  If I don't have the `^Callable` typehint for `f` the first example quietly returns `nil`.  Shouldn't it throw an exception "more than one matching method found" for the submit call since `f` is both `Runnable` and `Callable`?  If I define `f` using `let` like the following then the exception is thrown

```
(let [e (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newSingleThreadExecutor)]
  (let [f (fn [] "hello world2")]
    (try
      (.get (.submit e f))
      (finally (.shutdown e)))))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the type of `e` could not be inferred in

```
(def e (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newSingleThreadExecutor))
```

when I change this to

```
(def ^java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService e (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newSingleThreadExecutor))
```

then `(.get (.submit e f))` gives proper answer `"hello world"`.  Somehow clojure is inferring the correct type when `e` is defined using a `let` and thus does not require a similar type hint.

setting `*warn-on-reflection*` to `true` helped to debug this.